# Why is my inspector losing reference on play?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

[image]
This is before play

[image]
This is after play.

I have a very simple script. I am using [SerializeField] on a TMP_Text file. In the inspector I have dragged the text file from the Hierarchy into the serlialized field in the inspector of my UI Controller. When I click on play, the inspector drops the reference to the tmp and says there is nothing there. I have the ability to redrag the file once it is running and it will work fine.

Why am I losing the file on play??

```
[SerializeField] TMP_Text score;
int points;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    points = 0;
    score = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    score.SetText(points.ToString());
}

public void AddToScore(int score)
{
    points += score;
}
```

This is a very simple script. The file I am atttaching has no script or anythin to it. It is just a basic text mesh pro object.

Answer (score 1):

In awake you reassign score. The problem is you do a GetComponent which only searches the current GameObject. Since UIController does not contain a TMP_Text component it return null and so you lose the reference. If you just remove that line (score = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();) it will fix your issue

Comment: Ahhhhhh THANK you! I thought you always had to add 'GetComponent' in order to change the properties on something... Does this apply to every component that i attach in [SerializedField]? Do you only use GetComponent when you are accessing the component in that same gameobject??

EDIT: Nevermind I see what i did. I am assign it to get component. In this case I could have probably done score.GetComponent. right?